# How to have dynamic header using wicked_pdf to add page numbering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, page-numbering

So I have a header that I want on each page that looks  like this
[image: Pdf Report header] and I want the page number to appear where it says [page] by the user's name. Here is what I have so far, but it is not working:

In my controller:

```
render  pdf: "report",
        page_size: "Letter",
        layout: "pdf",
        template: "/results/report",
        footer: { 
            spacing: -265,
            html: { template: '/layouts/_report_header.html'} 
        },
        header: { 
            spacing: 3,
            html: { template: '/layouts/_page_header.html' }
        },
        margin: { 
            top: 20,
            bottom: 5 
        }
```

In my /layouts/_page_header.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head>
    <% user_id = session[:user_id] %>
    <% user = User.find(user_id) %>
    <script>
      function number_pages() {
        var vars={};
        var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for(var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = decodeURIComponent(z[1]);}
        var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
        for(var i in x) {
          var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
          for(var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="number_pages()">
    <div class="page_header inline">
          <h3 class="margin_none font_roboto">Nutrient Tracking Tool - Report</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="right font_roboto">
          <strong>User:</strong> <%= user.name %> | <span class="page">[page]</span></br>
      </div>
      <div>
          <hr class="line_break" color="dodgerblue">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

According to the documentation [here on github](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#page-numbering)

> Anything with a class listed in "var x" above will be auto-filled at render time.

this should cause the `span` of class page to display the current page number but it does not. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:** I think it may also be important to mention that adding `{ center: '[page] of [topage]' }` to the header of footer causes page numbers to display correctly:

[image: page number showing]

Answer (score 0):

Your markup and JavaScript are working fine for me.

As proof of example, I've added this question to the [Wicked PDF Issues](https://github.com/unixmonkey/wicked_pdf_issues/commit/32dfd430a6b6eae3bb1d21c10b86e25c250ac365) project and deployed it [here](http://wicked-pdf-issues.herokuapp.com/pages/issue_38311828).

PDF version [here](http://wicked-pdf-issues.herokuapp.com/pages/issue_38311828.pdf)

There are some padding issues with this minimal reproduction, but you can see the page numbering is working as expected.

What version of `wkhtmltopdf` are you using, and on what platform? Try upgrading or switching it out if possible.

Try experimenting with the following [wkhtmltopdf options](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt): `--enable-javascript`, `javascript-delay`, `--no-stop-slow-scripts`

Comment: I download it from [their website](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) because I was having trouble with their binary-gem with the filepath. It is version 0.12.3.2 (the most recent verion), and I am on Windows 7 Enterprise. My ruby version is old however (v 1.9.3) could that cause issues?

Comment: @an older version of Ruby should not cause this issue. I wonder if the Windows binary you have was compiled with the right options enabled. Try tweaking the JavaScript options first, then try swapping it out for another version (even an older one) if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Okay. I am a little confused on where these option are supposed to go though.. Are they supposed to go in the script or in the controller? Or somewhere else

Comment: In the controller call to `render pdf: 'mypdf', javascript_delay: 10000, no_stop_slow_scripts: true, extra: ' --enable-javascript'`

Comment: Those cause it to crash.`--enable-javascript` works alone but causes my headers to partially disappear leaving only the blue divider.

Comment: I think it may be important to mention that `{ center: '[page] of [topage]' }` works in the controller to add page numbering to the header or footer. I have added this to my question